# How to prevent html from clearing after submit

Tags: php, html

Sorry if my code is still quite long. I already removed some unnecessary stuffs but still quite long. But my question is quite simple.

At first the table shows all and it filters the table by clicking the button. My first question is:
 1. After I press the button the form is cleared and the select goes back to Users. How can make it so that even after I pressed the button the things I typed in the text box for example will still be there.

And my last question is as you can see I am using OR in my statement it should be AND, but if I used AND suppose the Emp Num is empty I will not get any result because in my statement it will be like empNum='' since the text box is empty. I don't know how to approach this problem so that it ignores empty textbox for the query.

```
<?php
$varSQL = "SELECT * FROM admintool.atUsers";

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$varSQL = "SELECT * FROM admintool.atUsers WHERE 

empNum='".$_POST['empNum']."' OR empLName='".$_POST['empLName']."' OR empFName='".$_POST['empNFName']."' OR empLevel='".$_POST['UserLevel']."'";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method='post' action='#'>
            <form method='post' action='#'>
            <fieldset style='width:auto;'>
                <legend>Filter Table:</legend>
                <label class='usersmodify'>Employee Number: </label><input type='text' name='txtEmpNum' class='usersmodify'>
                <label class='usersmodify'>Last Name: </label><input type='text' name='txtEmpLName' class='usersmodify'>
                <label class='usersmodify'>First Name: </label><input type='text' name='txtEmpFName' class='usersmodify'>
                <label class='usersmodify'>User Level: </label>
                    <select name='UserLevel' class='usersmodify'>
                        <option>User</option>
                        <option>Admin</option>
                    </select>
                <button type='submit' value='Submit' name='Submit' class='usersadd'>Filter Table</button>
            </fieldset>

            <table id='tblLOL'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Number</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Employee Level</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
                <?php        
                showTables($varSQL, $Link);
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
Function showTables($varSQL, $Link){
    $result = ExecuteQuery($varSQL, $Link);
    $alternate=1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($alternate%2==1){echo "<tr class='alt'>";}
        else{echo "<tr>";}$alternate++;
        echo "<td>".$row["empNum"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['empFName']." ".$row['empLName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['empLevel']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='#' name='edit' data-rowid=".$row['id']."><img     src='icons/edit.ico' alt='Edit' height='16' width='16'></a>&nbsp;";
        echo "<a href='test.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Greybox pop up' rel='gb_page_center[500, 500]'><img src='icons/cross.ico' alt='Delete' data-rowid='1' class='cross-icon' height='16' width='16'></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: To get the content of what user posted before do this: `<input type='text' name='txtEmpNum' class='usersmodify' <?php echo isset($_POST['txtEmpNum']) ? 'value="' . $_POST['txtEmpNum'] . '"' : ''; ?> >`

Comment: Thanks for this. A nice and simple solution for retaining that values in text boxes. I'll try to do the same logic for the select tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on your current setup. If you need security in addition to correctness just point that out!

```
<?php
$varSQL = "SELECT * FROM admintool.atUsers";

/* 
 * at that point I would really prefer storing all the input into an 
 * array, and adding it to our query in a second moment. The example 
 * will explain better 
 */
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $myInput = array(); // this will hold our data
    $i = 0; //variable which will be used as counter/array-index
    if (isset($_POST['empNum'])) {
        $myInput[i] = 'empNum="'.$_POST['empNum'].'"';
        $i++; // $i was 0. We used it to put an element in the i-th 
              // position, so we now need to increment it to move to 
              // the next one!
    }
    if (isset($_POST['empLName'])){
        $myInput[i] = 'empLName="'.$_POST['empLName'].'"';
        $i++;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['empNFName'])){
        $myInput[i] = 'empNFName="'.$_POST['empNFName'].'"';
        $i++;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['empLevel'])){
        $myInput[i] = 'empLevel="'.$_POST['empLevel'].'"';
    }
    /*
     * We ended up with our array, which now hold the pieces of the 
     * WHERE clause for which an input was present. Now we need to 
     * add the data to our query.
     * There is a function in PHP, implode(), which can take an array
     * and build up a string out of it, interponing between each couplet
     * of elements a separator at our choice. Let's try:
     */

     if (!empty($myInput)){ // $myInput must have at least 1 element
         $myWhereClause = implode(" AND ", $myInput);
         /*
          * Suppose the 1st, 3rd and 4th input where submitted: we now 
          * have $myWhereClause = "empNum='value1' AND 
          * empNFName='value2' AND empLevel='value3'"; now let's put all 
          * together.
          */

         $varSQL .= " WHERE ".$myWhereClause;
         // voilà, everything is concatenated :)
     }
}

?>
```

Coming to your first question, do you consider JavaScript/jQuery viable options? Because if this is the case you can send the POST request from jQuery and modify the elements you need "live", without needing a refresh.

Comment: What a wonderful solution for my where statement. Thank you for this. About my first question, I am fine with doing the isset() for retaining value. But if there is an easier way using jquery or javascript I'm open to study it.

Comment: Using jQuery you could do something like the following:

Comment: `var myVar = $.post ( "fileToCall", 
               { POST DATA },
               .done(function(data){
                        // this triggers if the request was succesful
                        // do something
               })
               .fail(function(){
                        // Ehrm, the request failed: let's warn the user and try to
                        // repair the 'damage' if possible
               })
        }`

In case the 'formal' example is not clear, feel free to comment, I'll repost back as soon as can :)
p.s.: sorry for the layout, it's a mess...

Comment: Don't know anything about jscript&jquery but I will study it. 

Also about the earlier example. It's working. Only one problem. Suppose I leave a text box blank. It still enters the isset clause. I'm not too sure but it seems that if I pressed the button even though the text box was empty it seems it is still counted as it is set so it enter it.

So my query will look like "SELECT * FROM admintool.atUsers WHERE empNum="123" AND empLName="" AND empFName="123" AND empLevel="User""

but it should be SELECT * FROM admintool.atUsers WHERE empNum="123" AND empFName="123" AND empLevel="User"

Comment: Well, if you still know nothing about JS/jQuery maybe I had better avoid creating confusion: for now the method you used is just as fine as a XHR via JS! For the error, I would suggest checking your code for typos, I will retest it in a moment just to be sure, but must be an incorrect syntax, somewhere!

Comment: I checked it seems I don't have any typo. And when I debug it and look at the values of $_POST superglobals. if I leave a box empty it's value is "" oppose to for example I put a 123 value in empNum it says it's value is "123"

Then when it reach the condition isset. It thinks that "" is a set value and enter its clause.

Comment: anyway I can work my way around it by putting a

        if($_POST['txtEmpNum']=='')
        {
            echo 'empty';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'not empty';
        }

inside the clause :)

Comment: Yeah, given the issue you could try checking for `if (data!='')` rather than `if (isset(data))`, it works nearly in the same way

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of what user posted before do this: `<input type='text' name='txtEmpNum' class='usersmodify' <?php echo isset($_POST['txtEmpNum']) ? 'value="' . $_POST['txtEmpNum'] . '"' : ''; ?> >`

Then about your query:

```
<?php
$varSQL = "SELECT * FROM admintool.atUsers";

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$varSQL = "SELECT * FROM admintool.atUsers WHERE 

empNum='".$_POST['empNum']."' AND (empLName='".$_POST['empLName']."' OR empFName='".$_POST['empNFName']."' OR empLevel='".$_POST['UserLevel']."')";
}
?>
```

Comment: BTW your code have huge security issues as your are not sanitizing the inputs. But this is another problem ...

Comment: Yes I'm just using simple sql since it is still in my localhost. But before I put it live I'll have to update it for sql injection